# Match strings in two files using awk and regexp

Tags: regex, awk

I have two files.

File 1 includes various types of SeriesDescriptions

```
"SeriesDescription": "Type_*"
"SeriesDescription": "OtherType_*"
...
```

File 2 contains information with only one SeriesDescription

```
"Name":"Joe"
"Age":"18"
"SeriesDescription":"Type_(Joe_text)"
...
```

I want to

1. compare the two files and find the lines that match for "SeriesDescription" and
2. print the line number of the matched text from File 1.

Expected Output:

`"SeriesDescription": "Type_*" 24 11` (the correct line numbers in my files)

"SeriesDescription" will always be found on line 11 of File 2. I am having trouble matching given the `*` and have also tried changing it to `.*` without luck.

Code I have tried:

`grep -nf File1.txt File2.txt`

Successfully matches, but I want the line number from File1

`awk 'FNR==NR{l[$1]=NR; next}; $1 in l{print $0, l[$1], FNR}' File2.txt File1.txt`

This finds a match and prints the line number from both files, however, this is matching on the first column and prints the last line from File 1 as the match (since every line has the same column 1 for File 1).

`awk 'FNR==NR{l[$2]=$3;l[$2]=NR; next}; $2 in l{print $0, l[$2], FNR}' File2.txt File1.txt`

Does not produce a match.

I have also tried various settings of `FS=":"` without luck. I am not sure if the trouble is coming from the regex or the use of "" in the files or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for posting a Good question. Could you please post sample of expected output too in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: @aheywood - You write: _`grep -nf File1.txt File2.txt` Successfully matches_ - but it does not with the shown file content (after removing `...`), so you have included wrong information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
{ val="" }
match($0,/^[^_]*_/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
}
FNR==NR{
  if(val){
    arr[val]=$0 OFS FNR
  }
  next
}
(val in arr){
  print arr[val] OFS FNR
}
' SeriesDescriptions file2
```

With your shown samples output will be:

```
"SeriesDescription": "Type_*" 1 3
```

---

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
{ val="" }                       ##Nullifying val here.
match($0,/^[^_]*_/){             ##Using match to match value till 1st occurrence of _ here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)  ##Creating val which has sub string of above matched regex.
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",val)    ##Globally substituting spaces with NULL in val here.
}
FNR==NR{                         ##This will execute when first file is being read.
  if(val){                       ##If val is NOT NULL.
    arr[val]=$0 OFS FNR          ##Create arr with index of val, which has value of current line OFS and FNR in it.
  }                       
  next                           ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(val in arr){                    ##Checking if val is present in arr then do following.
  print arr[val] OFS FNR         ##Printing arr value with OFS, FNR value.
}
' SeriesDescriptions file2       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

***Bonus solution:*** If above is working fine for you AND you have this match only once in your file2 then you can `exit` from program to make it quick, in that case have above code in following way.

```
awk '
{ val="" }
match($0,/^[^_]*_/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
}
FNR==NR{
  if(val){
    arr[val]=$0 OFS FNR
  }
  next
}
(val in arr){
  print arr[val] OFS FNR
  exit
}
' SeriesDescriptions file2
```

Comment: This works great. Unfortunately some Types have several _ in them for example: Type_A_*;Type_B_*; OtherType_A* etc. Can I change the match to be up until the asterisk?

Comment: @aheywood, oh ok, in that case try `match($0,/^.*\*/)` once and try.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the match to work better for my specific data. Matching at the second underscore ```^[^_]+_[^_]*_/``` and it worked.